# The role of the parameter in the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've read a lot of papers for differential equations, which study the existence , multiplicity, and/or nonexistence of solutions according to parameter $\lambda$. For example, consider the following elliptic differential equation
$\Delta u=\lambda f(u),~x \in \Omega$
$u=0,~\partial \Omega,$ where $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain and $
\lambda$ is a parameter.

What is the meaning or role of the parameter $\lambda$? Please let me know if you have any idea, physical example or comment for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Any physical meaning will depend on the physical context.  Mathematically, each value of $\lambda$ gives you a different equation (though they may be related), and the solutions will depend somehow on $\lambda$.  Investigation of how it depends on $\lambda$ may be worthwhile.

Sometimes, the assumption that $\lambda$ is very small or very large may allow a simplification to a solvable model, and the solution for general $\lambda$ might then be written  as a series in positive or negative powers of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you give some specific physical example?

Comment: Hi @0706, I don't know if this is what you're after, but if $f(u)=u$, then we would have the diffusion equation, and $\lambda$ would correspond to a diffusion coefficient (how quickly the material wants to disperse).

Comment: In an example such as $f(u)=u$, we can non-dimensionalize the equation, removing the parameter by an appropriate scaling of the independent variables.